# Erro do jquery ajax solicitando o rss

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando pegar o RSS do G1 quem vem em XML porém da erro de `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.` segue o código:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/brasil/",
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function (data) {}
});
```

Já pesquisei em vários lugares, tentei adicionar headers mas se sucesso, como posso resolver?

Comment: @Bacco infelizmente não consigo resolver com essa resposta

Comment: Colocar `crossDomain: true` no seu AJAX não funcionou?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário coloquei e não foi

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true,

Mas se quer uma boa dica olhe no https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ e vê a parte com requisição JQuery.